# How to call child composable lambda

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Root() {
    Scaffold(
            floatingActionButton = {
                FloatingActionButton(onClick = {}) {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite)
                }
            }
    ) {
        Child()
    }
}

@Composable
fun Child() {
    var textField1 by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    TextField(value = textField1, onValueChange = {textField1 = it})

    val validateAndMakeNetworkRequest = {

    }
}
```

How can I call `validateAndMakeNetworkRequest` from floating action button without state hoisting?
The code above just example, `Child` composable could be very deep

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass a callback functoin and function will take a function as an argument

```
@Composable
fun Child(onNext: (onClick: () -> Unit) -> Unit) {
// now you can call this function from parent
onNext() {
    Log.d("data", "clicked")
}
}

@Composable
fun Parent() {
var onClickForChild by remember {
    mutableStateOf({})
}
Child(onNext = { onClickForChild = it })
Button(onClick = { onClickForChild() }) {
    Text(text = "Next")
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't. In Jetpack Compose, we are not really calling funcions, there's a gradle plugin working some magic to simplfy our code, but, what's actually happening is that we are saying to the runtime "hey, this is the function I want to call" and the runtime calls it as many times as it sees fit to compose the screen.

It's easy to notice that if you out a `Log.d("some", "thing")` inside a composable function, the app may log it many times, even if we don't do anything.

I know that you sad "without state hoisting", but that's not how declarative works. You need a boolean stored in a state and an "if" using it whether to call a composable or not.

In case of a network request, you can separate it in a normal function, and call it inside you `FloatingActionButton` `onClick`.